# Parse.com register for Push Notifications

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm trying to add push notifications to my iOS app using Parse.com push notification service, but I'm running into problems with some of my devices not receiving notifications.

**Current code**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    Parse.setApplicationId("*****", clientKey: "*****")

    // Register for Push Notitications
    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {
        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.

        let preBackgroundPush = !application.respondsToSelector("backgroundRefreshStatus")
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")
        var pushPayload = false
        if let options = launchOptions {
            pushPayload = options[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] != nil
        }
        if (preBackgroundPush || oldPushHandlerOnly || pushPayload) {
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)
        }
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    }else {
        let types : UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    // Store the deviceToken in the current Installation and save it to Parse
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    if error.code == 3010 {
        print("Push notifications are not supported in the iOS Simulator.")
    } else {
        print("application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: %@", error)
    }
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

This seems to work on *some* devices (tested it on coworker's iPhone 5 - worked, tested on my boss' iPhone 6 - didn't work)

The code I currently use also gives me 2 warnings, which is (what I suspect to be) the cause of push notifications not working on every iDevice.

Warning 1:

> /Users/ds/code/rp-iOS/rp/AppDelegate.swift:43:25: 'UIRemoteNotificationType' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Use UIUserNotificationType for user notifications and registerForRemoteNotifications for receiving remote notifications instead.

Line 43:

```
let types : UIRemoteNotificationType = [.Badge, .Alert, .Sound]
```

Warning 2:

> /Users/ds/code/rp-iOS/rp/AppDelegate.swift:44:25: 'registerForRemoteNotificationTypes' was deprecated in iOS 8.0: Please use registerForRemoteNotifications and registerUserNotificationSettings: instead

Line 44:

```
application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
```

Now I'm confused about these warnings because I copied the code from the Parse.com documentation - so what am I doing wrong? It seems like this else clause provides backwards compatibility for devices that run older versions of iOS.

In my Parse.com Push console, I also get some errors:

[image: Parse.com push console]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to save your `PFInstallation` after you set its device token

Comment: Can't believe I missed that from the documentation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` try to add this line of code.

```
installation.saveInBackground()
```

To get rid of the warnings I suggest using this code (I've put that in static function for convenience and ability to reuse)

```
static func askForPushNotifications(){
  let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
  UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```